# Conceptual doubt in reading the domain of a relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can already see the heavy downvotes but any help will be appreciated.

Let there be a relation R and the domain of R is given by
$$\{x:(x,y)\in R\}$$

How should I convey this set if I am to read it out to someone?

My try was :"the set of all x such that x comma y belongs to R"

Is this right it does not make alot of sense to me .

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: Shouldn’t that be $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: if $S$ is where the relation $R$ is defined then $R\subseteq S\times S$, this means that $R$ is a subset of the Cartesian product $S\times S$.

Comment: @Tavish "$R$" denotes an arbitrary binary relation, that is, just some set of ordered pairs.

Comment: It’s *the set of all first components of members of $R$* or *the set of all first components of the ordered pairs in $R$*.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the domain of $R$ isn't quite right. It should be $$\{x:\color{red}{\exists y}((x,y)\in R)\}.$$ That is, the domain of $R$ is the set of things which are $R$-related to something; or, perhaps more smoothly, $x$ is in the domain of $R$ iff there is *some* $y$ such that $x$ is $R$-related to $y$. The definition you've given suggests that we're looking at some **specific** $y$; this would describe the *$R$-preimage* of the particular element $y$ (or of the particular set $\{y\}$ - there's some abuse of terminology here), but that's not the whole domain of $R$ in general.

(This is a situation where natural language is a bit clunky, unfortunately.)

Comment: How can I check that  {:∃((,)∈)} is a set?

Comment: @Eduardo Use the fact that $R$ itself is a set to begin with. You can either use the replacement axiom (scheme), or think about the details of the ordered pair notion and use the union axiom and separation axiom (scheme). (Of course $R$ does need to be a set in order for this to work - e.g. if we take $R$ to just be $\in$ itself, this breaks down since $\{x:\exists y(x\in y)\}$ is the universal class.)